# Finding the value of k using the factor

Tags: polynomials, factoring

> Suppose $5x - 2$ is a factor of $x^3 - 3x^2 + kx + 15$.  Find $k$.

I've tried getting the $x$ value of the factor $5x - 2 = 0$ and got $x= \frac25$ and replaced all the other $x$s with $\frac25$ and set the equation to be equal to $0$.
But I don't know if I'm doing right, show me the steps and value of $x$.

Comment: The factor theorem states that a polynomial $f(x)$ has a factor $(x-k)$ if and only if $f(k)=0$. So yes you are doing right.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of your work makes it sound like you're on the right track.

Let $f(x)=x^3-3x^2+kx+15$.  If $5x-2$ is a factor of $f(x)$, then by the remainder theorem, we have $f(\frac25)=0$.  Thus,

\begin{align}
f(x)&=x^3-3x^2+kx+15\\
f(\frac25)=0&=(\frac25)^3-3(\frac25)^2+k(\frac25)+15\\
0\color{blue}{\cdot125}&=\bigg(\frac8{125}-\frac{12}{25}+\frac25k+15\bigg)\color{blue}{\cdot125}\\
0&=8-60+50k+1875\\
-1823&=50k\\
k&=-\frac{1823}{50}
\end{align}

The moral of the story:  don't be alarmed if your final answer is not a number you expected!  Rational numbers are real numbers, too!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the method is fine and we obtain

$$\frac8{125} - 3\frac{4}{25} + k\frac25 + 15=0 \iff8-60+50k+1875 \iff k=-\frac{1823}{50}$$

and indeed

$$x^3 - 3x^2 -\frac{1823}{50}x + 15=\frac1{50} (5 x - 2) (10 x^2 - 26 x - 375) $$